# How to change admin panel link in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I completed my development on my local environment. The url on my local environment was samplesite.local

After I finished the development, I uploaded it to the server and the url was working but when I try to open admin panel of wordpress, it directs me to the local link.

For example, when I try to login this link:

> samplesite.com/wp-admin

then it goes to:

> samplesite.local/wp-admin

What is the problem here? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the values in the options table, as at present the option value  is referencing to your local development url, causing these errors.

You really need to read up on the codex before posting a question here.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

I believe this question has been asked many times here. Please use the search function of site before posting a question.

[Moving Wordpress Domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32021510/moving-wordpress-domain?s=1|3.7195)

Answer (score 0):

After Moving the files & Database. you need to change the domain name in database config. The easiest way to do it by using Search-Replace-DB Script.

Just Download the tool from here : 
https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Just fill ***samplesite.local*** in search and ***samplesite.com*** in replace and run the tool. it will do all the task automatically.

hope it will help you.